# How to set using tag and id as default for Katalon Studio record function?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, end-to-end, katalon-studio

Currently the record function in Katalon studio uses all possibilities to identify an element (i.e. tag, id, name, class, text and full XPath). For some reason the full XPath always fail to identify an element in actual testing, and text on element is something that changes a lot and does not matter to the testing in most case. Currently I need to manually unset the unnecessary identifier after each record. Is there a way I can tell the record function to use only tag and id to identify an element?

Comment: I think this is a great suggestion for them to add the configuration for default locators selection

Comment: That means there is no such function now?

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer from Katalon Forum. So as they said, this features will be implemented in later releases. 
https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/4368/how-does-katalon-studio-decides-which-identifier-to-be-used-while-automating-tests#latest